# A user inputs logical operator symbols or a number, invalid if enters character or string

Tags: c++

I've been trying to code this as sort of a beginner program for C++ to help me understand the language more but I don't really know how to tackle this.

Basically the program needs to only accept '+', '*', '/', '%' or numbers, otherwise if the user inputs a letter or a word, the program will say the input is invalid.

Here's what I've done so far

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
string x;

cout<<"Enter expression: ";
getline(cin,x);



if(x.find('*') != string::npos){

    cout<<"Multiplication";
}else if(x.find('/') != string::npos){

    cout<<"Division";
}else if(x.find('%') != string::npos){

    cout<<"Modulo";
}else if(x.find('+') != string::npos){

    cout<<"Addition";
}else{

    cout<<"Invalid!";
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? :) Looks like a fine start

Comment: How are you accepting numbers?

Comment: also what do you mean you're trying to understand the language :-) This example could be done so many different ways to "show off" C++'s different capabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling `std::getline()`, you can put `x` into a `std::istringstream` and then read integers and chars from that as needed, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;

    cout << "Enter expression: ";
    getline(cin, x);

    istringstream iss(x);
    int value1, value2;
    char op;

    if (iss >> value1 >> op >> value2)
    {
        switch (op)
        {
            case '*':
                cout << "Multiplication = " << value1 * value2;
                break;
            case '/':
                cout << "Division = " << value1 / value2;
                break;
            case '%':
                cout << "Modulo = " << value1 % value2;
                break;
            case '+':
                cout << "Addition = " << value1 + value2;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid operation!";
                break;
        }
    }       
    else
        cout << "Invalid expression!";

    return 0;
}
```